# Angular 8 test with httpClient does not send requests

Tags: angular, testing, httpclient

I'm trying to test a basic service but it seens like the httpClient is not sending the request to my local api even it says that passes to the test

```
describe('MyService', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports:[
        //HttpClientTestingModule,
        HttpClientModule,
        TranslateModule.forRoot(),
        RouterTestingModule.withRoutes([])
      ],
      providers:
      [
        MyService
      ]
    });
  });

  it('should return 1', inject([HttpClient,MyService],
    (httpClient: HttpClient, myService: MyService) => {
     const headers = {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Authorization': "Bearer token"
     }
     httpClient.get("http://localhost:60200/path?parameter=1", { headers: headers }).subscribe((myModel:MyModel)=>{
       expect(myModel.id).toBe(1);
     }); //pass to the test but didn't sent to the api
     myService.getById(parameter).subscribe((myModel: MyModel)=>{
        expect(myModel.id).toBe(1);
     }); //what I really want to test
  }));
});
```

Comment: How do you know that it's not requesting?

Comment: @EliasSoares I added the breakpoint in my .net api and if I change the url to anyting it would pass the test

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved, I just had to use TestBed.get, instead using injection, to get the service and use 'done' from jasmine to do asynchronous request.

```
  ...
  myService = TestBed.get(MyService);
  ...
  it('should return 1', (done) => {
     myService.getById(parameter).subscribe((myModel: MyModel)=>{
        expect(myModel.id).toBe(1);
        done();
     });
  });
```